# PIVOT possible for reporting this?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have the data structure below.  Basically I am allowing users (trusted members of my team) to create a predefined query to be run against a set of data.  They can specify the table name(s), database(s), categorical fields (essentially a GROUP BY), and aggregated value fields.  Because the query can include any number of categorical fields and any number of value fields I have made a pretty complex model to store all of it.  You can run the script below to create the model and insert some records.  Then select * from the view [rpt].[vwQueryStatsDetail] to get a sample of the results.

My question is - how can I display the results flipped the other direction to show, for instance, "Person Key", "Total Pay Amount", and "Record Count" as headers and all values for those columns?  I was thinking some kind of pivot but I haven't had any luck with that yet.  I'm trying to get it in a single SQL statement and avoid dynamic SQL or limiting myself to a single reporting layer like SSRS or something.

**EDIT:** Check out the SQL Fiddle sample I put together.  Easier for most people than running all of the script below.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d0e4/4

Thank you!

==============================================================================

```
    CREATE SCHEMA di
    GO
    CREATE SCHEMA rpt
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [di].[ClientQuery](
        [ClientQueryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [QueryID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [DBListID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [Active] [bit] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ClientQueryID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[Query](
        [QueryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [TableNameMatchPattern] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [Active] [bit] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[QueryCategoryField](
        [QueryCategoryFieldID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [QueryID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Expression] [varchar](800) NOT NULL,
        [Description] [varchar](800) NOT NULL,
        [Ordinal] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryCategoryFieldID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[QueryInstance](
        [QueryInstanceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ClientQueryID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryInstanceID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[QueryInstanceRecord](
        [QueryInstanceRecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [QueryInstanceID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [TableName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryInstanceRecordID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory](
        [QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [QueryInstanceRecordID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [QueryCategoryFieldID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Value] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue](
        [QueryInstanceRecordValueID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [QueryInstanceRecordID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [QueryValueFieldID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Value] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [di].[QueryValueField](
        [QueryValueFieldID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [QueryID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Expression] [varchar](800) NOT NULL,
        [Description] [varchar](800) NOT NULL,
        [Ordinal] [int] NOT NULL,
        [AggregationType] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
        [HavingValue] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [RecordTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryValueFieldID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[ClientQuery] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[ClientQuery] ([ClientQueryID], [QueryID], [DBListID], [RecordTimestamp], [Active]) VALUES (1, 1, 81, CAST(0x0000A2C9010BCA28 AS DateTime), NULL)
    GO
    INSERT [di].[ClientQuery] ([ClientQueryID], [QueryID], [DBListID], [RecordTimestamp], [Active]) VALUES (2, 2, 18, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A5FFCA AS DateTime), 1)
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[ClientQuery] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[Query] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[Query] ([QueryID], [Description], [TableNameMatchPattern], [RecordTimestamp], [Active]) VALUES (1, N'PersonKey excessive count', N'tblMiningCache^_^_[1-9]%^_^_P^_[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]', CAST(0x0000A2C9010BB343 AS DateTime), NULL)
    GO
    INSERT [di].[Query] ([QueryID], [Description], [TableNameMatchPattern], [RecordTimestamp], [Active]) VALUES (2, N'Unique EID values', N'tblMembers_EligibiltyHistoryLatest', CAST(0x0000A2CA00A5B3FF AS DateTime), 1)
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[Query] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryCategoryField] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryCategoryField] ([QueryCategoryFieldID], [QueryID], [Expression], [Description], [Ordinal], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (1, 1, N'PersonKey', N'Person Key', 1, CAST(0x0000A2C9010BE0F2 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryCategoryField] ([QueryCategoryFieldID], [QueryID], [Expression], [Description], [Ordinal], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (3, 2, N'TapeID', N'Tape ID', 1, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A6A711 AS DateTime))
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryCategoryField] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstance] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstance] ([QueryInstanceID], [ClientQueryID], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0x0000A2CA00999F0D AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstance] ([QueryInstanceID], [ClientQueryID], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A6DF1A AS DateTime))
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstance] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] ([QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryInstanceID], [RecordTimestamp], [TableName]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0x0000A2CA009D65B3 AS DateTime), N'tblMiningCache__123__P_2014-01-30')
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] ([QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryInstanceID], [RecordTimestamp], [TableName]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(0x0000A2CA009D6609 AS DateTime), N'tblMiningCache__123__P_2014-01-30')
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] ([QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryInstanceID], [RecordTimestamp], [TableName]) VALUES (3, 2, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A70FA5 AS DateTime), N'tblMembers_EligibilityHistoryLatest')
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] ([QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryInstanceID], [RecordTimestamp], [TableName]) VALUES (4, 2, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A84356 AS DateTime), N'tblMembers_EligibilityHistoryLatest')
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ([QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryCategoryFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'ABC999123', CAST(0x0000A2CA009A5638 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ([QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryCategoryFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (2, 2, 1, N'DEF123888', CAST(0x0000A2CA009A64A5 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ([QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryCategoryFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (3, 3, 1, N'ZZ801999A', CAST(0x0000A2CA009A7CAF AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ([QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryCategoryFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (5, 3, 3, N'1370', CAST(0x0000A2CA00A81EE4 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ([QueryInstanceRecordCategoryID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryCategoryFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (6, 4, 3, N'1015', CAST(0x0000A2CA00A8AC47 AS DateTime))
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, CAST(1001.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA009AAA6F AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (2, 2, 1, CAST(1500.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA009BB3B9 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (3, 3, 1, CAST(9000.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA009BCC7E AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (4, 1, 2, CAST(1000000.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA00A13E8F AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (5, 2, 2, CAST(55123.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA00A1493A AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (6, 3, 3, CAST(99123945.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA00A15541 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ([QueryInstanceRecordValueID], [QueryInstanceRecordID], [QueryValueFieldID], [Value], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (7, 4, 3, CAST(90210.000000 AS Decimal(19, 6)), CAST(0x0000A2CA00AA4535 AS DateTime))
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] OFF
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryValueField] ON 

    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryValueField] ([QueryValueFieldID], [QueryID], [Expression], [Description], [Ordinal], [AggregationType], [HavingValue], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (1, 1, N'LineKeyID', N'Record Count', 1, N'COUNT', N'>1000', CAST(0x0000A2C9010C12F7 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryValueField] ([QueryValueFieldID], [QueryID], [Expression], [Description], [Ordinal], [AggregationType], [HavingValue], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (2, 1, N'PayAmount', N'Total Pay Amount', 2, N'SUM', NULL, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A05245 AS DateTime))
    GO
    INSERT [di].[QueryValueField] ([QueryValueFieldID], [QueryID], [Expression], [Description], [Ordinal], [AggregationType], [HavingValue], [RecordTimestamp]) VALUES (3, 2, N'DISTINCT EID', N'Unique Employee ID Count', 1, N'COUNT', NULL, CAST(0x0000A2CA00A6510F AS DateTime))
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [di].[QueryValueField] OFF
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[ClientQuery] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[ClientQuery] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[Query] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[Query] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[QueryCategoryField] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[QueryInstance] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[QueryInstanceRecord] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[QueryInstanceRecordCategory] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[QueryInstanceRecordValue] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [di].[QueryValueField] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecordTimestamp]
    GO

    CREATE VIEW [rpt].[vwQueryStatsDetail]
AS SELECT cdb.ID as ClientID,
         q.QueryID,
        q.Description AS QueryDescription,
        cq.ClientQueryID,
        qir.TableName,
        qir.QueryInstanceRecordID,
        qcf.Description AS CategoryDescription,
        qirc.Value AS CategoryValue,
        qvf.Description AS NumericValueDescription,
        qirv.Value AS NumericValue,
        qi.RecordTimestamp AS QueryInstanceDateTime
    FROM di.Query AS q JOIN di.ClientQuery AS cq ON q.QueryID = cq.QueryID
                    JOIN di.QueryInstance AS qi ON qi.ClientQueryID = cq.ClientQueryID
                    JOIN di.QueryInstanceRecord AS qir ON qir.QueryInstanceID = qi.QueryInstanceID
                    JOIN di.QueryInstanceRecordCategory AS qirc ON qirc.QueryInstanceRecordID = qir.QueryInstanceRecordID
                    JOIN di.QueryInstanceRecordValue AS qirv ON qirv.QueryInstanceRecordID = qir.QueryInstanceRecordID
                    JOIN dbo.vwClientDatabases AS cdb ON cq.DBListID = cdb.Id
                    JOIN di.QueryCategoryField AS qcf ON qcf.QueryCategoryFieldID = qirc.QueryCategoryFieldID
                                              AND qcf.QueryID = q.QueryID
                    JOIN di.QueryValueField AS qvf ON qvf.QueryValueFieldID = qirv.QueryValueFieldID
                                            AND qvf.QueryID = q.QueryID



    GO
```

Comment: While we could run all that, posting some sample data or creating a demo on SQLFiddle.com would be much easier for us to work with.  The output of your query is all we need to see.

Comment: Every other time I've asked this kind of question I get "we can't help you without DDL" :)  Here's my best shot at appending the data.

Comment: I haven't used SQLFiddle.com before, pretty cool!  So go here and click Run SQL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d0e4/4